# Passing data from one form to the action method of another form within the same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a typed view called `AccountSetup.cshtml` with two forms:

```
@model ViewModel 

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{       

// input form stuff
<input type="submit"  id="Submit"" />

}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

// other input form stuff
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CreateAccount", "AccountSetup")'" />
}
```

The first form sends the data to the this post method and that works fine.  However when I submit the second form which goes to the Get method, I lose the model data. Wouldn't the `TempData.Keep` retain all the data for all posts back to the controller?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AccountSetup(ViewModel AccountInfo)
{
        TempData["AccountInfo"] = AccountInfo;

        // writing to database
        TempData.Keep("AccountInfo");
        return View(AccountInfo);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateAccount(ViewModel AccountInfo)
{
        if (TempData["AccountInfo"] != null)
        {
            // functionality 
            var data = TempData["AccountInfo"] as ViewModel
        }

        return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every request (get/put/post) is completely independent of the next (imagine your code is running on a cluster of servers), so just because you keep some data 'locally', it's not going to exist on the next call to the server (or one of the other servers in the cluster).  A specific TempData instance only exists for the duration of 'AccountSetup'.

If you want something to be in the view model for CreateAccount, you will nee to use things like @Html.HiddenFor in your view.

In reality though, you would want to only store maybe the 'account id' in the view and reload the actual data from a database as you don't want to 'believe' anything the client sends you as any hacker would be able to pass whatever data they require to your server, so you MUST verify everything.

Comment: The ID is created when the first form is submitted.  There is no id before that.  Can I populate the hiddenfor field dynamically after the first form is posted? Would it go inside of the first form?  Or outside of both forms?

Comment: There is no 'dynamic' to this, the sequence goes: Get create page, post create page (which generates id).  If you imagine each 'page' in 2 parts, a 'get me the web page' and 'the web page wants to create a record'.  Usually, there would be 2 controller functions with the same name, one without a view model (the get function) and one with a view model (the post).

Comment: So you're saying that if no ID is created by the first form (Get) then it's not possible to access that data in the 2nd form?  In that other action method I mean...